# Using :nth-child(odd) selector on div image

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm having a little bit of trouble using CSS's `:nth-child(odd)` selector.  It seems to apply the CSS rules to every image when I select it based on a div class.

For example:

```
.class img:nth-child(odd) { margin-right:10px; }
```

and it's resulting in all of them being selected.  Tried using

```
img.class:nth-child(odd) { margin-right:10px; }
```

and get the same results.  http://jsfiddle.net/7mUDG/

Does it work for only table elements or something?  Am I selecting it incorrectly?

Many thanks, SO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your :nth-child selector is one level too deep. look at http://jsfiddle.net/demchak_alex/7mUDG/2/

Answer (score 5):

```
.hello a:nth-child(odd) {
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used 2n-1 and that worked fine

http://jsfiddle.net/tjharrop/7mUDG/3/

Also changed margin to a red border to make it more easily visible